# simplecart.js Images not Showing in IE8 on blogger.com site

Tags: javascript, css, image, internet-explorer-8, blogger

Images are scrunched up in IE8

iframed: 
http://techmobile.com/storeBETA.html

original site:
http://store-techmobile.blogspot.com/

Why is it doing this? It is alright in IE9.

here's code for the insertion of the image:

```
<th class="item_thumb" id="thumb" width="45%"><a href="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-  
k1EQIca2tCw/TdtZUjHTeGI/AAAAAAAACAs/vNwQwZAVkaI/s1600/blue.gif" onblur="try 
{parent.deselectBloggerImageGracefully();} catch(e) {}"><img alt="" border="0" 
id="BLOGGER_PHOTO_ID_5610175970378217570" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-
k1EQIca2tCw/TdtZUjHTeGI/AAAAAAAACAs/vNwQwZAVkaI/s400/blue.gif" style="cursor: hand; 
cursor: pointer; display: block; height: 164px; margin: 0px auto 10px; text-align: 
center; width: 148px;" /></a></th>
<td><input class="item_add" type="button" value="Add to Cart" /></td>
</tr>
```

Is the item thumb width getting scrunched in IE8? I'd like to pinpoint what the cause is before changing settings and writing code. This code is part of a table of code inserted into the backend of blogger.com so a table shows up for posting pics, prices, description details etc. As per BloggerMints instructions:
http://www.bloggermint.com/2011/05/shopping-cart-blogger-template/

I'm on a mac so I don't have access to IE8's developer tools. Any insights much appreciated.

And I'm kinda confused on how to write the code because it's not a simple CSS divert rewrite like:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie8.css" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the float: left on the wrapping span. Either remove that, or set it's width to 100% or similar. You probably should do this for only IE8 and below.